# Can I use ediff against a svn branch?

Tags: svn, emacs, diff, emacs-ediff

I frequently have conflicting changes in another subversion branch I need to merge into my branch; ediff would go a long ways to making that easier.

However, it seems psvn.el and ediff only support diffing against a revision in the same branch, unless I'm reading the docs wrong.  It would be nice to hit a hotkey, be prompted for a branch name, and merge away.  Alas my lisp skills are non-existent aside from tweaking my .emacs file.

Any recommended solutions?  Yes, I can check out the other branch and merge as files, but it sure would be nice to not have to do it that way.  Thanks.